# Google Transliterate not working with https domains

Tags: ssl, jsapi

Google transliteration (ctrl + G) is not working on https domain. It is showing following error in browser console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/transliterate/v1/customtransliteration' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '[http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=aa&ime=transliteration_en_ar&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=*callbacks*._0ie41tj63](http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=aa&ime=transliteration_en_ar&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0ie41tj63)'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You can check above issue on following link:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/transliterate/v1/customtransliteration

Comment: Does this question actually have anything to do with PHP?

Comment: I want to add this in my PHP site.

Comment: I am also having same problem

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo  Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706699/5057418