# Google Transliteration Suggestion CSS not proper

Tags: angular, google-translate, transliteration

I followed the steps to solve the problem of Transliteration API not being served over HTTPS: [Javascript google transliterate API not served over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667348/javascript-google-transliterate-api-not-served-over-https?rq=1)

I extracted Google JSAPI & Transliteration.I.js to my own file and added https.

But After that, the suggestions pop up in a div at the bottom of the page and not like the usual dropdown.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Impossible to say anything without some code. Could you post a stackblitz? or some minimal working example?

Comment: @BrunoFenzl check my answer I figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a step by step process:**

First, there's a link to API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
```

Second, Visit the API link above and search the contents as given below:

```
google.loader.ServiceBase = 'https://www.google.com/uds';
```

You need to replace the link of `google.loader.ServiceBase = 'yourfile.js';`

note: `yourfile.js` is a script created by you.

And to do that - you need to create two separate JavaScript files. Why? because the google.loader.ServiceBase is inside google.com/jsapi

step 1: Create two JavaScript files - lets say `main.js` and `extra.js`

step 2: save the contents of `https://www.google.com/jsapi` to `main.js`

step 3: save the contents of `https://www.google.com/uds/api/elements/1.0/7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8/transliteration.I.js` to `extra.js`

step 4: In extra.js - find `qi="http://www.google.com"` and replace with `qi="https://www.google.com"` - remember http is changed to https and save it.

step 5: Now back to main.js - you have to find the `google.loader.ServiceBase = 'https://www.google.com/uds';` and replace with `google.loader.ServiceBase = 'extra.js';` and save it.

step 6: Call both the files in your index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="extra.js">
```

step 7: Copy CSS from this [link](https://codepen.io/varunjoshi995/pen/dLJPOb) & add it to a file transliteration.css. Add the following line to index.html

```
<link type="text/css" href="assets/google/js/transliteration.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This should get you the correct CSS required for showing the transliteration popup.